# Get all PortfolioItems for a workspace (using Rally .Net Rest API)

Tags: rally

I am trying to fetch all portfolio items for a specific workspace. In the request, I am setting the limit to a very large number '1000000' and I am not setting the page size. For some reason, I am getting 'System out of memory' exception'. Another option I tried is to specify a filter 'LastUpdateDate > 1/1/2000' in the query, but that also doesn't work.
Can you please let me know what is the best way to fetch all portfolioitems (all fields) for a specific workspace? Here is a code snippet that I am using.

```
QueryResult result = null;
Request request = new Request(objectType);
request.Workspace = "/workspace/" + workspaceID;
request.Limit = limit;
request.Start = startIndex;
request.ProjectScopeDown = false;
request.ProjectScopeUp = false;
result = rally.Query(request);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably play around with different page sizes.  If you're not specifying anything it may be defaulting to as low as 20, so you're incurring a huge amount of network overhead.  The max page size wsapi supports is 2000.

Additionally, depending on the size of your workspace you may just have too much data to keep in memory at one time.  You may be able to write it to temp files, or increase the available memory for your .NET process.

What are you trying to do, that you need all of your pi's for the whole workspace?